# Cannot post html when running on amazon-ec2 with mono and mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mono, amazon-ec2

I have a site hosted on an Amazon Linux AMI box running mono through lighttpd.  In the admin section of my site, I have a form that let's me create blog entries.  Since I want to be able to store html, I set up my save controller action as follows:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult CreateBlog(Blog model) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        ContextFactory.BlogManager.Save(model);
        return RedirectToAction("Blogs");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Everything works fine locally, but when I deploy the code to our amazon instances, I get the following exception:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Body=\"asd<br>asdas\").
System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerousr> Request.Form value was detected from the client (Body=\"asd<br>asdas\").<br>
 at System.Web.HttpRequest.ThrowValidationException (System.String name, System.String key, System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 <br>
  at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString (System.String key, System.String value, RequestValidationSource source) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 <br>
  at Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicValidationHelper.LazyWebROCollection.Validate (System.String key, System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 <br>
  at Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicValidationHelper.LazyWebROCollection.Get (System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 <br>
  at System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection.get_Item (System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 <br>
  at ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was actually able to fix it by adding `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>` to my web.config

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the data that's getting posted back contains a `<`.  This is disallowed to prevent possible script injection attacks.  [Here's a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client) on the topic that should be able to help you ou.

Comment: Yes, but as mentioned in my post, I specifically wanted to post HTML, and that's why I added the ValidateInput(false) to my controller.  I was actually able to fix it by adding <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/> to my web.config.  I'l mark this as answered when the system lets me, looks like there's an 8 hour cap.

Comment: @rsparkyc: Ah right, sorry I missed that.  Glad you were able to resolve it.